# Regular expression grouping in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have variable contains: `No such file or directory at ./EMSautoInstall.pl line 50.`

I want to create variable contains `No such file or directory` and another one contains `at ./EMSautoInstall.pl line 50.`

my REGEX is: `my ( $eStmnt, $lineNO ) = $! =~ /(.*[^a][^t])(.*)/;`

when I print both variable, the first one contains `No such file or directory` but the second one is empty.

Why this happen?

Comment: For general Perl regex help, start with `perldoc perlrequick` and when you've conquered that, move on to `perldoc perlre`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you *really* have that string in the `$!` variable? Because normally, the `at line...` part is added by `die` and `warn`. I suspect you simply have

```
$! = "No such file or directory";
```

And your regex matches because it allows the empty string

```
/(.*[^a][^t])(.*)/
```

I.e. the second capture also matches nothing, and the first capture can be anything that does not end with `at`.

To confirm,

```
print $!;
```

Should print `No such file or directory`.

Comment: @M_E Mystery solved. :) When in doubt, the `Data::Dumper` module is a nice tool for debugging: `print Dumper $variable`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) here with a lookahead assertion makes more sense than regex captures:

```
my ( $eStmnt, $lineNO ) = split /(?=at)/, $!;
```

Comment: What's the meaning of "?=" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
((?:[^a]+|\Ba|a(?!t\b))+)(.*)
```

the idea is to match all that is not a "a" or a "a" that is not a part of the word "at"

details:

```
(                 # first capturing group
    (?:           # open a non capturing group
        [^a]+     # all that is not a "a" one or more times
      |           # OR
        \Ba       # a "a" not preceded by a word boundary
      |           # OR
        a(?!t\b)  # "a" not followed by "t" and a word boundary
    )+            # repeat the non capturing group 1 or more times
)                 # close the capturing group
(.*)              # the second capturing group
```

You can improve this pattern replacing the non-capturing group by an atomic group and the quantifiers by possessive quantifiers. The goal is to forbid the record by the regex engine of backtrack positions, but the result stay the same:

```
((?>[^a]++|\Ba|a(?!t\b))++)(.*+)
```

Comment: Could you explain this please? It is the first time for me to see that because I am new in Perl.

Comment: Thanks alot @Casimir et Hippolyte

Comment: I want to ask you from where I can gain these knowledge of REGEX

Comment: @M_E: regular-expressions.info, pcre.org/pcre.txt, http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.pattern.php, http://www.rexegg.com/